# NoSQL with Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework-4, nosql

Can we use an ORM framework like MS Entity Framework and connect to a NoSQL database to make use of the benefits provided by NoSQL databases ?
If yes, is there any existing NoSQL implementation which can be used with the Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the only NoSQL Database I've come across that supports entity framework code first is [BrightstarDB](http://brightstardb.com/), which is essentially an RDF triplestore. It is fairly new, but seems promising and has the added benefit of being [open source.](https://github.com/BrightstarDB/BrightstarDB)